# Angular - Set parent component's .m-content style

Tags: angular, metronic

I'm trying to set height of parent component from child but it isn't applied no matter how I try to set it

```
:host .m-content{
height: 100% !important; }
```

In browser code looks like this where `m-road-train` is my component:[image]

Comment: Please share  your code. and explain your problem clearly. so we can help you.

Comment: @BearNithi I added code form browser's debugger.

Comment: share your component.html and component.ts file, because, what type of viewencapsulation it has?

Comment: @BearNithi It has default Emulated encapsulation. Component's code doesn't matter here. Even if i't empty cause I want to set style to parent's element.

Comment: do you want to set style from child to parent?

Comment: @BearNithi Yes, exactly )

Comment: That's not possible. Tatyana. bcz of viewencapsulation in angular. you can write your css in parent component.

Comment: @BearNithi Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Bear Nithi wrote in comments - "That's not possible." The only way is to write css in that component or its parents.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean your component have a class named 'm-content'?

<=> eg: `<app-mycomponent class="m-content"></app-mycomponent>`

To ensure your style is correct, put it directly in your debugger's browser.

You can also put it in your global style `style.css`

Comment: I meant that my component is within a div which style I want to change. I added a screen of code from debugger. The style is correct - cause when I put it directly in browser's debugger - it looks fine. And I can'r put this style to global style file cause I wan't this style to apply only when my component is shown as child.

Comment: try to not use this :host

Comment: Doesn't work cause .m-content element is not within my component :(